# How can I make multiple similar Fortran modules with different 'use' statement?

Tags: oop, module, fortran

I have a module that exports data to file.
It exports similar data from different modules.
Currently, I have an export module for each type of data and the only difference is a single line.
Here is a simple example

```
module cat
  contains
  character(len=10) function name()
    name = 'Meowser'
  end function name
end module cat

module dog
  contains
  character(len=10) function name()
    name = 'Barkster'
  end function name
end module dog

module export_cat
  use cat
  contains
  subroutine export_name
    print *, name()
  end subroutine export_name
end module export_cat

module export_dog
  use dog
  contains
  subroutine export_name
    print *, name()
  end subroutine export_name
end module export_dog

program main
  use export_dog
  call export_name
end program main
```

The export modules are exactly the same except for the "use" statement.
I don't want to maintain multiple copies of the same export module.
Is there a way to add the subroutines in my export module to all my different modules?

Comment: Hi, try to come uo with a question title which describes your problem, not just the topic, that is already described by the tags `fortran` and `module` below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can be done using INCLUDE.

```
 !*************
 ! common.i90
 subroutine export_name
   print *, name
 end subroutine export_name

!*************
! elsewhere...

module export_cat
  use cat
contains
  include 'common.i90'
end module export_cat

module export_dog
  use dog
contains
  include 'common.i90'
end module export_dog
...
```

Note that as written, each export_name procedure is specific, and you will get name clashes in a scope that accesses two or more specific procedures that have the same name.

~~~

The OOP approach (since you tagged it) would typically be to define a type that acts as a common parent to cats and dogs (animal perhaps), an export procedure operating on a polymorphic argument of type animal then calls the a procedure that implements type specific behaviour through a binding.

```
module animals
  implicit none
  public :: export

  type, public, abstract :: animal
  contains
    procedure(animal_name), deferred, nopass :: name
  end type animal

  abstract interface
    function animal_name()
      import animal
      implicit none
      character(:), allocatable :: animal_name
    end function animal_name
  end interface
contains
  subroutine export(obj)
    class(animal), intent(in) :: obj
    print *, obj%name()
  end subroutine export
end module animals

module cats
  use animals
  implicit none
  private
  type, public, extends(animal) :: cat
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: name
  end type cat
contains
  function name()
    character(:), allocatable :: name
    name = 'Meowser'
  end function name
end module cats

module dogs
  use animals
  implicit none
  private
  type, public, extends(animal) :: dog
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: name
  end type dog
contains
  function name()
    character(:), allocatable :: name
    name = 'Barkster'
  end function name
end module dogs

program main
  use animals
  use cats
  use dogs
  class(animal), allocatable :: x
  x = cat()
  call export(x)
end program main
```